# Adding a button displaces the floating div on the side

Tags: html, css, button, layout, css-position

When I add this button it causes the floating element on the side to move down (the pink block). I don't understand why and I don't want to fix the issue by changing margins everywhere. And `absolute` positioning doesn't work because it messes up my floats. I'm still a newbie, so a few things might be wrong.

As you can see here, the pink box moved down when the button was placed:

[image]

```css
/* BUTTON */
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 20px;
    padding: .5em 2em .55em;
    -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
    -moz-border-radius: .5em;
    border-radius: .5em;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 1640px;
    margin-left: 110px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #00a087;
}

#toprow {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #00a087;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.clearFix {
    clear: both;
}

#largeBox {
    margin-top: 85px;
    width: 750px;
    height: 950px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-left: 240px;
    background: url('football2.jpg');
}

#botRightBox {
    width: 750px;
    height: 475px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: 750px;
}

#botTopLeft {
    width: 750px;
    height: 475px;
    background-color: pink;
    margin-left: 750px;
    float: right;
}

#row {
    width: 1500px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-left: 240px;
}

#content {
    width: 1500px;
    height: 850px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-left: 240px;
}

#footer {
    width: 2000px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: #00a087;
}


#sideNav {
    margin-left: 110px;
    width: 130px;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    max-height: 1900px;
    background-color: #00a087;
}

.menu {
    line-height: 48px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px initial black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

    a:hover {
        background-color: #fff;
    }

#lazy {
    line-height: 650px;
}
```

```html
<header id="navbar">2222222222222222222222222222</header>
<div id="toprow">djksadkd</div>
<div id="sideNav">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Account</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Live Events </a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Football</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Baseball</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Soccer</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Basketball</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Hockey</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">MMA</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">eSports</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Tennis</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Cricket</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Golf</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Badminton</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Handball</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Rugby</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Snooker</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Table Tennis</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Volleyball</a></li>
        <li><a id="lazy" href="#"><font color="#00a087">LAZYSOLUTION</font></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="largeBox">
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="final.html">
            <button type="button" id="topBtn">Sign Up Now</button></a>
    </div>
    <div id="botTopLeft">
        <h1>OUR
            <br>
            PROMOTIONS</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="botRightBox"></div>
    <div class="clearFix"></div>
</div>
<div id="row"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, why can't you insert the button into `#botTopLeft` div?

```css
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 20px;
    padding: .5em 2em .55em;
    -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
    -moz-border-radius: .5em;
    border-radius: .5em;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 4em;
}

header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 1640px;
    margin-left: 110px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #00a087;
}

#toprow {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #00a087;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.clearFix {
    clear: both;
}

#largeBox {
    margin-top: 85px;
    width: 750px;
    height: 950px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-left: 240px;
    background: url('football2.jpg');
}

#botRightBox {
    width: 750px;
    height: 475px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: 750px;
}

#botTopLeft {
    width: 750px;
    height: 475px;
    background-color: pink;
    margin-left: 750px;
    float: right;
}

#row {
    width: 1500px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-left: 240px;
}

#content {
    width: 1500px;
    height: 850px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-left: 240px;
}

#footer {
    width: 2000px;
    height: 350px;
    background-color: #00a087;
}


#sideNav {
    margin-left: 110px;
    width: 130px;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    max-height: 1900px;
    background-color: #00a087;
}

.menu {
    line-height: 48px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px initial black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

    a:hover {
        background-color: #fff;
    }

#lazy {
    line-height: 650px;
}

/* ADD THIS STYLE */
.button-wrapper {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<header id="navbar">2222222222222222222222222222</header>
<div id="toprow">djksadkd</div>
<div id="sideNav">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Account</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Live Events </a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Football</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Baseball</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Soccer</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Basketball</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Hockey</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">MMA</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">eSports</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Tennis</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Cricket</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Golf</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Badminton</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Handball</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Rugby</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Snooker</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Table Tennis</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#">Volleyball</a></li>
        <li><a id="lazy" href="#"><font color="#00a087">LAZYSOLUTION</font></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="largeBox">
    <!--REPLACE THIS <div style="text-align: center">-->
    <div id="botTopLeft">
      <div class="button-wrapper">
        <a href="final.html">
            <button type="button" id="topBtn">Sign Up Now</button></a>
      </div>
        <h1>OUR
            <br>
            PROMOTIONS</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="botRightBox"></div>
    <div class="clearFix"></div>
</div>
<div id="row"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="footer">...</div>
```

**Notes:**

1. You won't put a `button` into a `a` tag. If you want link with `button` style, style it with `css`.
2. You need to close `a` tag with `</a>` but not `<a>`.
3. You can't set `float:bottom right`. You can set `float` as `right` or `left` - not `bottom` and not multiple.